# Invoking websocket ServerEndpoint before client invoking onOpen()

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I have created a websocket ServerEndPoint.
websocket Server is working fine. How can I invoke websocket ServerEndPoint class when Tomcat starts up. This is to pre-initialize some services.

One option I tried is to start a servlet( web.xml) to invoke the ServerEndPoint. Its working. But doesn't look like a good solution.

Is there any other best practices I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a class that `implements ServletContextListener`

Then override the `public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` method